# How can I manage on using for loop number into a txt files

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Good evening everyone, I am David Tzu a 9years old, May I ask about txt files in python... I currently trying to read the inside .txt files with proper number alignment..

Sample.txt files consist of:
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
Seven
Eight
Nine
Ten

here's my code:

```
with open('Sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
    for x in range(1, 11):
        print(x, contents)
```

I would like to get a result the same as this one
expected output:

```
1 One
2 Two
3 Three
4 Four
5 Five
6 Six
7 Seven
8 Eight
9 Nine
10 Ten
```

I'm really sorry for my bad english hope you all understand what I am trying to convey..

Comment: `print(x, contents[x - 1])`

Answer (score 0):

You could change readlines in to readline and move it into the for loop, like the example below:

```
with open('Sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    for x in range(1, 11):
        print(x, f.readline())
```

That is assuming there is a new line in your text file between each number.

EDIT TO REMOVE NEWLINE:

```
with open('Sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    for x in range(1, 11):
        print(x, f.readline().replace("\n",""))
```

Or similar to Larry the Llamas comment still using readlines:

```
with open('Sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
    for x in range(1, 11):
        print(x, contents[x - 1].replace("\n",""))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply sir.. is it possible to remove the \n from that?

Comment: Why yes you can, simply add .replace("\n","") on to f.readline() like: print(x, f.readline() .replace("\n","")

Comment: Thank you thank you so much sir Liam for guiding me

Comment: No problem David! I've added an extra example using Larry the Llamas comment for readlines

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('Sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    for x in range(1, 11):
        print(x, f.readline().strip('\n'))
```

Try this.

Comment: it result to this sir 1 one
2 one
3 one
4 one
5 one
6 one
7 one
8 one
9 one
10 one

Comment: I tried the readlines, it says AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'